# Access 2016 VBA Sub - "Item not found in this collection" error on RecordsetClone

Tags: vba, ms-access-2016

I have a form that shows results from the following query:

```
SELECT Database.Contact_ID, Database.[Full Name], Database.[Job Title], 
Institution.Institution, Database.Email, Database.[Email 2], Database.[Work 
phone], Database.[Work phone 2], Database.Mobile, Database.Notes, Database. 
[Date created], [Keyword Junction].Keywords, Database.[Record Type]

FROM Institution INNER JOIN (Keywords INNER JOIN ([Database] INNER JOIN 
[Keyword Junction] ON Database.[Contact_ID] = [Keyword Junction].Contact_ID) 
ON Keywords.Keyword_ID = [Keyword Junction].Keywords.Value) ON Institution.ID 
= Database.InstitutionLookup

WHERE (((Keywords.Keyword) Like [Enter Keyword] & "*"))

ORDER BY Database.[Record Type] DESC , Database.Surname;
```

On the form I've created a sub linked to a button, this is the VBA:

```
Private Sub Send_Email_Click()    
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim bcc As String
Dim Name As String
Call fOSUserName
Name = LCase(fOSUserName) & "insertdomainhere"

     Set rs = Forms!KeywordSearch.RecordsetClone
      If rs.RecordCount > 0 Then
          rs.MoveFirst
          Do
              If Not IsNull(rs!Email) Then
                  bcc = bcc & rs!Email & ";"
                  rs.MoveNext
             Else
                  rs.MoveNext                            
               End If                   
         Loop Until rs.EOFa                          
    DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, , , Name, , bcc, , , True

    End If
    Set rs = Nothing   
    End Sub
```

When I click the button I get "Error 3265: Item not found in collection". The debugger shows the issue is on the "If Not IsNull(rs!Email) Then" line, apparently the Email field isn't in the recordset. The only issue I can think of is that the query is working with a table that has a multivalued field.

Appreciate any suggestions as to how to fix this error.

Comment: Try `Dim frm As Form` `Set frm = Forms("KeywordSearch")` then intelisence `frm. RecordsetClone` ??

Answer (score 0):

i think the error is on then line    Set rs = Forms!KeywordSearch.RecordsetClone

i assume that keywordSearch is not a subform so it's can't have the (recordsetclone) property which is a form property and even then if  KeywordSearch is indeed somekind of a subform then it should be Set rs = Forms!KeywordSearch.form.RecordsetClone

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, KeywordSearch is definitely a form (not a subform). I tried the suggested edit but the problem persists. Interestingly I have the same code on a different form and it works fine, the only difference I can see is the mutlivalued field.